# Área da interseção de dois polígonos

Tags: r

Como calcular a área da interseção entre dois polígonos? Por exemplo:

```
a = matrix(c(0 ,0 ,2 ,0 ,2 ,2 ,0 , 2, 0, 0), byrow = T, ncol = 2)
b = matrix(c(.5, 0 ,1 , 1, 1.5, 0, .5, 0), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
```

A primeira coluna representa o eixo x e a segunda o eixo y, o polígono é fechado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finalmente consegui calcular.

Dado

```
a1 = matrix(c(0 ,0 ,2 ,0 ,2 ,2 ,0 , 2, 0, 0), byrow = T, ncol = 2)
b1 = matrix(c(.5, 0 ,1 , 1, 1.5, 0, .5, 0), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
```

Outro exemplo

```
a2 = matrix(c(0,0,2,0,2,2,0,2), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
b2 = matrix(c(1.5,.5,3,0,2.25,2), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
```

## Interseção

```
library(sp)
interseccao <- function(a,b){
  a1 = as(a, "gpc.poly")
  b1 = as(b, "gpc.poly")
  res = intersect(a1, b1)
  res = as(res, "matrix")
  res
}
```

Aplicando a função `interseccao` temos as coordenadas do polígono.

## Área

A função que calcula a área de um polígono convexo qualquer é dada pela equação de Shoelace no sentido anti-horário.

```
area_poligono = function(poligono){
  a = poligono[,1]
  b = poligono[,2]
  area1 = area2 = 0
  for(i in 1:length(a)){
    if(i < length(a)){ 
      area1 = area1 + (a[i]*b[i+1] - a[i+1]*b[i])
    }
    else{
      area2 = area2 + (a[i]*b[1] - a[1]*b[i])
    }
  }
  area = .5*(area1 + area2) 
  area
  }
```

Comment: Wagner, você não pode postar a sua função que calcula a área de um polígono?

Comment: Bem pensado. Usei a equação de [Shoelace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula).

Comment: No package `sp` ainda é possível usar a função `area.poly` para calcular a área.

Answer (score 7):

Você pode obter uma aproximação usando [Método de Monte Carlo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_Monte_Carlo):

```
a = matrix(c(0 ,0 ,2 ,0 ,2 ,2 ,0 , 2, 0, 0), byrow = T, ncol = 2)
b = matrix(c(.5, 0 ,1 , 1, 1.5, 0, .5, 0), ncol = 2, byrow = T)

library(sp)

interseccao <- function(a,b, n = 100000){
  xmin <- min(a[,1], b[,1])
  xmax <- max(a[,1], b[,1])
  ymin <- min(a[,2], b[,2])
  ymax <- max(a[,2], b[,2])

  x_aleatorio <- runif(n, min = xmin, max = xmax)
  y_aleatorio <- runif(n, min = ymin, max = ymax)

  pontos_em_a <- point.in.polygon(x_aleatorio, y_aleatorio, pol.x = a[,1], pol.y = a[,2])
  pontos_em_b <- point.in.polygon(x_aleatorio, y_aleatorio, pol.x = b[,1], pol.y = b[,2])

  proporcao_intersec <- mean(pontos_em_a == 1 & pontos_em_b == 1)

  area_intersec <- (xmax-xmin)*(ymax - ymin)*proporcao_intersec

  return(area_intersec)
}

interseccao(a,b)
[1] 0.50368
```

No Método de Monte Carlo, pontos aleatórios são gerados em uma área da qual você já sabe a área. Em seguida determina-se a proporção de pontos que ocorrem na área que você deseja calcular, no caso, na intersecção dos polígonos. Essa proporção multiplicada pela área em que os pontos foram gerados, devolve a área desejada.

Claro que deve existir um algoritmo que calcule a área exata, mas se uma aproximação for o suficiente para você, está aqui.

Comment: O problema @Daniel é que preciso calcular a área de uns 5000 polígonos e usar Monte Carlo vai ficar muito pesado, mas solução é bastante interessante.

Comment: Wagner, você pode dar uma ideia da finalidade disso, acho que ajudará entendermos.

Comment: @WagnerJorge concordo que pode ficar pesado, para calcular essa quantidade demoraria uns 3min (o tempo de execução da função está em torno de 35 ms). Enfim, essa é só uma idéia, de repente você pode abrir mão da precisão tirando uma amostra menor para o Monte Carlo e a assim acelerar o cálculo. Já ouvi dizer que é melhor perder tempo de processamento do que tempo programando :P

Answer (score 6):

Conforme o link abaixo, acesse a **dissertação de mestrado** do **Sergio Lifschitz** que trata disso, e que usarei de exemplo para explicar o que pode fazer.

[Dissertação de mestrado - Sergio Lifschitz](http://www.maxwell.vrac.puc-rio.br/9412/9412.PDF)

A Figura abaixo refere-se à **Página 53, Figura [A3-2]**.

[image: Intersecção de polígonos]

O que você precisa fazer com o **algoritmo** em questão é **achar as coordenadas das intersecções**, e por exclusão, **ficar somente com os polígonos resultantes (como se tudo fosse uma única figura) para calcular a área total**.

As **coordenadas das intersecções entre os polígonos** podem ser encontradas por meio do **cálculo das coordenadas da intersecção de duas retas**, que é simples, uma vez que você tenha gerado **a equação de cada reta** (que também é simples) e isso dá para fazer com **cada conjunto de quatro coordenadas**, **um par para cada reta**.

Para o cálculo da área total que precisa, **dá para fazer por meio de triângulos**, ao conectar as coordenadas de modo que todas dividam a figura final como um todo em triângulos, **como representei abaixo**:

[image: Um único polígono divido em triângulos]

**SUGESTÃO:**

Veja que **havendo coordenadas coincidentes** (exatamente iguais dos dois polígonos, você pode **considerá-las como uma só**, e assim, no final irá ficar com cada coordenada da figura completa.

Depois, **pelas áreas internas dos polígonos** (na dissertação e em outras publicações há indicações de como identificar a parte interna do polígono), **gerar cada triângulo e calcular cada área na sequência**.

A equação da **área de um triângulo** é:

**A = (b x h) / 2**

Onde:

**A** = área do triângulo

**b** = base do triângulo

**h** = altura do triângulo

Basta calcular o tamanho da base e o mesmo para a altura.

Espero ter ajudado, ou pelo menos, apresentado um caminho. Boa sorte!

Comment: O quadrado e o triângulo são apenas exemplo, a ideia é que sejam polígonos quaisquer, podendo estar contidos, intersectados ou não.

Comment: Eu tentei, era algo próximo a isso que precisava?

Comment: agradeço demais o empenho, estou refletindo sobre a ideia. Eu consegui a pouco programar algo que calcula a área de qualquer polígono convexo (meu interesse), o desafio agora é só formar o polígono produto da intersecção. Se consegui formar o polígono, resolvo o problema. Pela manhã eu coloco essa ideia em prática.

Comment: Ótimo, veja na dissertaçäo que lá ele indica como fazer o algoritmo. se conseguir apresente a soluçäo ou pelo memos como chegou lá. Casos como esse me interessam e infelizmente näo posso dedicar o tempo que gostaria para apresentar a soluçäo.