# Operação com listas de tamanhos muito grandes

Tags: r, loop, lista

Tenho um código que calcula a área da interseção entre dois polígonos e para isso uso listas para guardar as coordenadas dos vértices dos polígonos, no entanto são muitos polígonos e tá levando em média 6h para rodar todo o código. Vocês sabem alguma operação com lista que pode ajudar a minimizar o procedimento?

## Meu código

```
require(dplyr); require(rgeos); require(sp)
sim.polygons = function(objects, vertex){
  polygons = NULL
  for(i in 1:objects) polygons[[i]] = matrix(runif(vertex*2), ncol = 2)
  return(polygons)
}

teste = function(lista1, lista2, progress = F){
  lista1 = lapply(lista1, as, Class = "gpc.poly")
  lista2 = lapply(lista2,  as, Class = "gpc.poly")
  res = matrix(0, nrow = length(lista2), ncol = length(lista1))
  for(k in 1 : length(lista1)){
    for(l in 1 : length(lista2)){
      res[l, k] = area.poly(intersect(lista1[[k]], lista2[[l]])) #Gargalo do código
    }
    if(progress == T) print(k)
  }
  res
}
#exemplo
a = sim.polygons(50, 3) #no meu problema objects = 144 e vertex = 3
b = sim.polygons(100, 3) #objects = 114^2 e vertex = 3

teste(a, b, T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não consegui agilizar o seu código a não ser propondo uma solução que rode em paralelo.

```
teste2 <- function(lista1, lista2, progress = F){
  lista1 = lapply(lista1, as, Class = "gpc.poly")
  lista2 = lapply(lista2,  as, Class = "gpc.poly")

  res <- plyr::laply(lista2, function(l2){
    plyr::laply(lista1, function(l1){
      area.poly(intersect(l1 , l2)) #Gargalo do código
    })
  },.parallel = T)

  res
}
```

Note o argumento `.parallel = T`.
Em seguida você precisa registrar o backend:

No Windows:

```
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
```

No Linux:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(2)
```

Em que **2** é o número de núcleos do seu processador (talvez ele tenha mais).

```
a = sim.polygons(10, 3) #no meu problema objects = 144 e vertex = 3
b = sim.polygons(20, 3) #objects = 114^2 e vertex = 3
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  v1 = teste(a,b,F),
  v2 = teste2(a,b,F),
  times = 5
)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
   v1 569.4241 629.3930 819.8292 833.3761 889.4672 1177.4855     5
   v2 445.0611 465.1625 548.7329 483.9004 598.9802  750.5603     5
```

Com dois núcleos o tempo não reduz tanto, mas se o seu computador tiver 4 talvez a redução seja signifcativa.

O problema é que a própria função `area.poly(intersect(a , b))` é lenta:

```
> a <- as(a[[1]], "gpc.poly") 
> b <- as(b[[1]], "gpc.poly")
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+     area.poly(intersect(a , b)) 
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
                       expr    min      lq     mean median      uq    max neval
 area.poly(intersect(a, b)) 2.9008 2.97925 3.146169 3.0493 3.33235 4.0275   100
```

Veja que no meu caso ela é chamada 200x:

```
> 10*20*3.146169 
[1] 629.2338
```

O que daria este tempo. Ou seja, a manipulação dos resultados não está adicionando tanto tempo a mais do tempo de execução da função.

```
> 144^3*3.146169/1000/60
[1] 156.5735
```

Mesmo sem capturar os resultados, o tempo estimado seria de approx. 2h30.

Comment: Substituí a `area.poly` por uma [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/132222/%C3%81rea-da-interse%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dois-pol%C3%ADgonos/133443#133443) e o tempo já caiu bastante, mas vou esperar um pouco para ver se alguém consegue diminuir o time. Caso não, você leva. Obrigado!